# Plotting frequency distributions

Tags: r, plot, frequency

I am trying to plot a simple frequency distribution and am having trouble. I have looked at all the other explanation already on this forum and I have no idea what the people are saying.

Basically, I have a data set like this

breathing rate per min 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16

number of people who have that breathing rate, respectively (frequency)
10,9,11,14,10,6

When I make a bar plot, with the breathing rate in the x axis and the frequency in the y axis, the values in the y axis are all jumbled up and not in any order or scale. Can you please help me? FYI, I am very new to this program.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- 11:16
y <- c(10,9,11,14,10,6)

barplot(y, names=x, main="Some fancy title")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Would you also be able to tell me a few other things. Like how to get the sd and mean? And how I can accomplish this plot with the "plot builder" tab?

Comment: @azums, you should ask a different question if you have a different question.

Comment: Try `mean(y)` and `sd(y)`. I don't know what you mean by the plot builder tab.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: djas I will be sure to do that in the future.
Andire, since you responded, let me respond back. I tried that but I dont get the right answer. It seems like the program is treating y and x as separate data still. I suppose I could just create one variable and input 11 10 different times and 12 9 different times and so on. But I was hoping for a more efficient method. 
I am using R 32-bit. The question about the plot builder tab was in regards to a GUI called deducer but I am not using that anymore now.

Comment: Take a look at `rep()` and `seq()`.